# In a batch file I want to run an exe with command line args which are contained in a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments

In a batch file I would like to open and run an .exe with command line arguments. But instead of listing all the arguments--there are a lot--I would like to put the arguments in a file and then put the name of the file after the .exe file.

Like this: test.exe args.txt

But that doesn't work or test.exe @args.txt

Thanks! I'm on windows 7.

Comment: If you can type them all in a text file, why can't you just type them in the batch file instead? `test.exe arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 ...` works.

Comment: I can't type them all into the batch file because the exe file needs to use args that are generated by another program which is called by an earlier line in the batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "args="
FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%a IN ("%~1") DO SET "args=!args! %%a"
ECHO executablename %args%

GOTO :EOF
```

Which you'd run as

```
thisbatchname yourtextfilename
```

Note that this will simply **show** the generated instruction on-screen, you'd need to remove the `echo` keyword and insert your executablename to actually use it.

If you want to vary the executablename, then all you'd need to do is remove `executablename` and insert your executablename as the first line of `yourtextfilename` **or**

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "args="
FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%a IN ("%~2") DO SET "args=!args! %%a"
ECHO "%~1%" %args%

GOTO :EOF
```

where you'd run it as

```
thisbatchname executablename yourtextfilename
```

which allows you to run any executable against the parameter-list included in your file.

Comment: Thanks Magoo! Works for me. After looking at what you wrote and some other stuff I see I can also do:    @echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in (testArgs.txt) do start cmd /K simple4.exe %%i"
PAUSE    for a batch file I can just click.